# scipy.signal.firwin lowpass filter acts like highpass filter

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

When designing low/high/bandpass filters I encountered the problem that they do not work as expected (see code and output).
I want to isolate one of the three frequency peaks (the one with the lowest frequency with lowpass filter, etc.). However, the wrong peak is isolated... Does anyone know what my mistake is?

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import signal
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def create_single_freq_state(N, w):
        """
        Creates a state that only contains the frequencies in w. Outputs array with N entries.
        """
        res = np.exp(2.0*np.pi*w[:,np.newaxis]*np.arange(N)/N*1j)
        return np.sum(res, axis=0)

    def band_pass_filter(f1, f2, numtaps, window="hamming"):

        fil = signal.firwin(numtaps, [f1, f2], pass_zero=False, fs=2*numtaps, window=window, scale=False)
        return fil

    def high_pass_filter(f, numtaps, window="hamming"):

        fil = signal.firwin(numtaps, f, pass_zero=False, fs=2*numtaps, window=window, scale=False)
        return fil

    def low_pass_filter(f, numtaps, window="hamming"):

        fil = signal.firwin(numtaps, f, pass_zero=True, fs=2*numtaps, window=window, scale=False)
        return fil

    def plot_freq_response(fil):

        fs = 2*len(fil)
        w, h = signal.freqz(fil, 1, worN=2000)
        plt.plot((fs * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label="Hamming window")
        plt.show()

    def plot_func(f):

        x = np.arange(1, len(f)+1)  
        plt.plot(x, f, color ="red")  
        plt.show()

    #create state with several frequencies (those contained in the variable ws)
    N = 60
    ws = np.array([15, 30, 50])
    f = create_single_freq_state(N, ws)


    numtaps = 60-1
    freq1 = 19.9
    freq2 = 40.0

    #choose filter
    fil = low_pass_filter(freq1, numtaps)
    #fil = band_pass_filter(freq1, freq2, numtaps)
    #fil = high_pass_filter(freq2, numtaps)

    #plot signal in fourierspace
    plot_func(np.fft.fft(f))
    #plot frequency response
    plot_freq_response(fil)
    #plot result of the application of the filter
    plot_func(np.absolute(np.fft.fft(np.convolve(fil, f, mode="same"))))
```

Output:[The output of my code. The wrong frequency is isolated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmTSd.png)

Comment: You have `*1j` in the denominator of your `create_single_freq_state` function. Is this intentional? Also, I would recommend not using `mode="same"` in the convolution, because when the signal and filter are roughly the same length, edge effects are important.

Comment: Oh I thought writing it this way would mean that it is in numerator... I changed the line to res = np.exp(2.0*np.pi*1j*w[:,np.newaxis]*np.arange(N)/N), but nothing changed. Concerning the mode in the convolution, if I change the mode, results only get worse...

Comment: You're correct that the`1j` is in the numerator, sorry. Anyway the point about making `f` a real only signal stands. Then, you can use `np.fft.rfft`, which will remove the need to think about the 2-sided transform. Also try making your signal `f` much longer than your filter `fil`, like at least 10 times as long. This will remove the effect of the starting and ending transients and allow the filter output to reach a steady state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your frequencies are so high that they appear as DC and a low frequency (this is called aliasing, and is a consequence of the Nyquist sampling theorem). The fact that you're working with a complex input signal, and that your signal is short relative to your filter, make this hard to see.

I changed `ws` to be `ws = np.array([7.5, 15, 25])`, and changed your first call to `plot_func` to be `plot_func(np.abs(np.fft.fft(f)))` (because one of the peaks is entirely in the complex part of the transform). Now the input and output graphs look as follows:
[image: input with three peaks]
[image: output with one peak]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Is there a way I can achieve the isolation of the peaks not by shifting them but rather by manipulating the size of the filter/the nyquist frequency (i.e., the parameter fs that I pass to signal.firwin)? The number of samples needs to stay constant as well. This might be a very stupid question, I have the feeling that I have not quite understood the process.

Comment: The Nyquist frequency is going to be half your sample rate, so if you want to analyze frequencies from 0 to 20 kHz for instance you have to sample at > 40 kHz. You should take care that frequencies that might alias from above the Nyquist frequency into the analysis band are rejected by an anti-alias filter before sampling. For your signal, what is the sampling setup, and is there a reason you were using a complex signal in your test?

Comment: Ok I understood everything a lot better now. Concerning your remarks:

-)Do you know how I can implement an anti-alias filter in python? 

-)The problem is that I am not really measuring. I am constructing the signal myself. However, due to the constraints of the problem, I can only know the values of the signal at times {0, 1/N, 2/N, ..., (N-1)/N}. Thus I will never be able to filter frequencies higher than N/2. That is not a (big) problem. Being able to filter lower frequencies should be sufficient. I hope that this is possible using an anti-alias filter!

Comment: I didn't realize you're constructing the signal. In that case, you need to take care that you don't introduce frequency content above Fs/2 in your construction. Anti-alias filters are needed when sampling continuous data, and when changing the sample rate of already sampled data. To implement a filter in python, you can design a filter as you're doing, then use either `np.convolve` or `scipy.signal.lfilter` to apply the filter. The nice thing about `lfilter` is it returns the filter state so you can continue filtering a long signal.